# Unable to insert record with windows form in c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008

The purpose of this is to allow user to input data in winform, then it will return the primary key in message box on success.

However, I run into an error when it was run in debug mode, it seems that the record was not able to insert into the database. Any helps?

I checked the database connection is fine, stored procedure was tested. System wise, visual studio 2010 with SQL server 2008 r2 standard

The code is as follow:

```
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connection to database " + error.ToString());
    }

    try
    {
        DateTime date = dtDate.Value.Date;
        string CommentSite = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        string Revisit = cboRevisit.Text;
        string CustomerGroup = cboCustomerGroup.Text;
        string CommentText = txtComment.Text;
        int CommentValue1 = Int32.Parse(cbo1.Text);
        int CommentValue2 = Int32.Parse(cbo2.Text);
        int CommentValue3 = Int32.Parse(cbo3.Text);
        int CommentValue4 = Int32.Parse(cbo4.Text);
        int CommentValue5 = Int32.Parse(cbo5.Text);
        int CommentValue6 = Int32.Parse(cbo6.Text);
        int CommentValue7 = Int32.Parse(cbo7.Text);
        int CommentValue8 = Int32.Parse(cbo8.Text);

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(@"InsertCommentData", myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@WeekEnding", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentDate", date));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentSite", CommentSite));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Revisit", Revisit));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CusomterGroup", CustomerGroup));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentText", CommentText));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue1", CommentValue1));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue2", CommentValue2));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue3", CommentValue3));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue4", CommentValue4));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue5", CommentValue5));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue6", CommentValue6));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue7", CommentValue7));
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CommentValue8", CommentValue8));
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        MessageBox.Show("Record saved! ID: " + newId + "\n" + "Please write down the number in the card top right hand corner");

    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to add/update record " + error.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();  
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you get an exception?  If not, then we need the contents of the stored proc as well.

Comment: `an error` and the error is......?

Comment: what does `Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();` do?

Comment: I just upload the error screen

Comment: rt2800: the statement is to retrieve the new primary key then show in the message box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems pretty straightforward: you do not have `EXECUTE` privileges for this sproc.  More specifically, the user account under which you're running the app lacks it.  Apparently in your testing environment, you do have privs - or at least, whoever ran the tests does.

To give such access, the database owner can run this:

```
 GRANT EXECUTE ON InsertCommentData TO [user name]
```

Comment: It works, however I have to comment out the Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar(); to make it work, how can I retrieve the new primary key in C#?

Comment: I'd need to see the inside of the sproc to make a guess.  When I have a procedure which creates a record, I generally pass back the new ID in an `OUT` param rather than the return value.  I can paste in sample code if you like.